# PHP Having problems with find and replace in LARGE CSV

Tags: php, csv

I am writing a PHP script so that I can do a find and replace in a large CSV file. I wrote this script:

```
// FIND AND REPLACE
$sourcePath = 'custom.csv';
$tempPath = $sourcePath . 'temp';
$source = fopen($sourcePath, 'r');
$target = fopen($tempPath, 'w');
while(!feof($source)) {    
    $line = preg_replace ("village", "village/",fgets($source));
    fwrite($target, $line);
}
fclose($source);
fclose($target);
unlink($sourcePath);
rename($tempPath, $sourcePath);
```

But I am getting these errors,

```
Warning: feof() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given
Warning: fgets() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given
Warning: preg_replace(): Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash
```

Comment: How about: `file_put_contents("custom.csvtemp", str_replace("village", "village/", file_get_contents("custom.csv")));` ?!

Comment: File is way too big to load to memory, hence I have to use fgets to load the file bit by bit.

Comment: probably be faster using some command line (os) tools

Comment: I was thinking that I used the exec command to use iconv but is there one for sting replace if there was that would be great. Do you know if there is one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$source = fopen($sourcePath, 'r');` isn't returning what you think it is.

It's likely returning false, which typically happens when PHP can't find the file at the path you provided. If you're *certain* the file exists, you should confirm that the user executing the script has the proper permissions to read the file.

You're second issue regarding `preg_replace()` is being caused by not using delimiters. They are needed in the first argument.

```
$line = preg_replace ("/village/", "village/",fgets($source));
```

However, regular expressions aren't needed with this simple of a replacement. You should instead use `str_replace()` and the script should run faster.

Your code should look like this:

```
<?php
$sourcePath = 'custom.csv';
$tempPath = $sourcePath . 'temp';
$source = fopen($sourcePath, 'r');
$target = fopen($tempPath, 'w');
if($source){
    while(!feof($source)) {    
        $line = str_replace("Village\\", "Village",fgets($source));
        fwrite($target, $line);
    }
} else {
    echo "$sourcePath not found, or using the wrong permissions.";
}

fclose($source);
fclose($target);
unlink($sourcePath);
rename($tempPath, $sourcePath);
?>
```

Comment: Hi I need need to replace "Villege\" with just "Villege". I treid to execute this $line = str_replace("Villege\", "Villege",fgets($source));

But get the error "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'Villege' (T_STRING"

Comment: You've included a backslash in the first argument, which is escaping the double quote that should be enclosing the argument. You need to add another backslash before to the first backslash to let PHP know that it is part of the string (don't worry, you will still only be matching against the 1 backslash). Also, if you're _searching_ the line for Village\\, Village\\ should be the second argument.  

`$line = str_replace("Villege", "Villege\\",fgets($source))`

Comment: More info on str_replace(): http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

More info on the backslash issue: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.single

Comment: I looked at the manual `mixed str_replace ( mixed $search , mixed $replace , mixed $subject [, int &$count ] )` and I think my command needs to be, as the manual says the first variable is search and I am searching for "Villege\" should it not be `$line = str_replace("Villege\\","Villege",fgets($source));`

Comment: I changed the code to make it more simpler. But the String isnt being replaced at all now. `$sourcePath = 'EstablishmentExport.csv';
$targetPath = 'EstablishmentExporttarget.csv';
$source = fopen($sourcePath, 'r');
$target = fopen($targetPath, 'w');

while(! feof($source))
  {
  $line = str_replace("Villege\\","Villege",fgets($source));
  fwrite($target, $line);
  }

fclose($source);
fclose($target);`

Comment: I've updated my answer to reflect the change in `str_replace()` - after testing it, it seems to work just fine. The simple striped down version of your code works as expected too, however _you've spelled Villege instead of Village in your `str_replace()`_.

Answer (score 0):

You are not checking if fopen is actually returning a file pointer resource or a false result. It is likely returning false and throwing the warning that a boolean is provided.

Also, you could use:

```
$line = str_replace("village", "village/", fgets($source));
```